# In create-react-app, my component won't compile because a static arrow function comes back undefined

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, es6-class, arrow-functions

I have the following React component. I'm using `create-react-app`, which is supposed to [support static class fields](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#supported-language-features-and-polyfills), but this does not compile and, instead throws this error:

```
./src/scenes/Settings/components/UserSettings.js
  Line 7:   'onTempRangeChange' is not defined        no-undef
```

My understanding is that the arrow function should be binding the context of `onTempRangeChange` to the class, which should be the same `this` referenced in the prop passed to `TemperatureRange`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { setTempRange } from '../actions';
import TemperatureRange from './TemperatureRange';

class UserSettings extends Component {

  onTempRangeChange = (tempRange) => {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    dispatch(setTempRange(tempRange));
  }

  render() {
    const { tempRange } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <TemperatureRange
          tempRange={tempRange}
          onTempRangeChange={this.onTempRangeChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default UserSettings;
```

Comment: Do you get this error for this component or for the TemperatureRange component, also dispatch wont be available unless you use `connect`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri For this component. Also, connect is done on the container for this scene - that isn't an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

I figured it out that was because my `.eslintrc` was not set right to accept "Class Fields and Static Properties".

I changed it to use just the Create React App eslint config.

Make your `.eslintrc` like so:

```
{
  "extends": ["react-app"]
}
```

It should work now.